# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

This is my model class.Here we are using setters and getters methods to initialize variables:

```
package org.koushik.javabrains.dto;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {
    @Id 
    private int userId;
    private String userName;
    public int getUserId() {
         return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
         this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
    }    
}
```

This is my model object and assigning values to the variables created in model class:

```
package org.koushik.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
//import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.koushik.javabrains.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUserName("First User");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
                                        .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.beginTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
session.beginTransaction().commit();
```

with

```
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Note using Spring's [`@Transactional`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) would remove the need to manage the transactions yourself

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to begin transaction within a transaction by calling begin transaction

while committing again, this causes above exception.

and message clearly says nested transaction is not supported.

so

create single transaction for a session like below and use the same thorough out your session

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

session.save(user);

tx.commit();
```